# why select * from t_user where id >=10000 limit 5 scan so many rows

Tags: mysql

The table info is below and It has near 10 million rows in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_user` (
      `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'user id',
      `user_name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'user name',
      `nick_name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'nick name',
      `portrait` varchar(128) DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'portrait url',
      `password` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'user password',
      `create_time` datetime NOT NULL,
      `update_time` datetime NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `uni_idx_un` (`user_name`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10080960 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

---

The explain of this sql `select * from t_user where id >=10000 limit 5;` can be seen here:

[image]

My question is why it need to scan so many rows(near 5 millions) while the id field has index? I think it only need to scan 5 rows because it can use primary index to skip the rows where `id < 10000`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html - try order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will not scan 5 million rows.

First of all, the number shown is just an estimate, e.g. a very rough guess of how many rows *might* get scanned with this index choice. It is calculated to help the optimizer make its decisions.

Additionally, the effect of the limit is not actually reflected in that number at all. It shows you the value it would have had without the limit (but with that index). Try changing the value for the limit, the row estimate will not adjust (assuming the execution plan stays the same).

The estimate value was already calculated in a different step and for a different reason, and the decisionmaking around the limit is done at a different place. And while it would be trivial in your specific case to say how many rows will get scanned at most (it could be less, so even in the simplest of cases there is some uncertainty), in most cases, it really isn't.

Try e.g. your table with `where nick_name = 'yates'` or `where id >= 10000 and nick_name = 'yates'`. What should be the correction if you add a `limit 1`? It could be anywhere between "reduce to 1 row" and "no effect at all".

So noone made a recalculation of the estimated rows, which is a very rough estimate to begin with, to include the estimated effect of the limit, which would also be mostly guesswork. Just to be clear, MySQL is of course aware of the limit and can pick a different index/execution plan if you add a limit. It will just not recalculate that value.

To see the actual rows scanned for your query, you can use e.g. [the profiler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html) (look at the column `rows_examined`) or, starting with MySQL 8.0.18, you could use [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`,](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-analyze) which will run the query and show the actual rows read (and the time it took).